# auto-click the SUBMIT button?

Tags: php

If the user manually clicks the 'submit' button, i use this code:

if (isset($_POST['submit_findall'])) {  ...

But what what code should I use if I want to activate this from within a script ?

Thanks!

Comment: if it's not javascript but PHP script, why not just to fake this variable, `$_POST['submit_findall']=1; include 'register.php';`? I don't understand why you have to double this code anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')`  is bullet proof indicator of the POST form submit

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_findall'])) { 
    // Something
}
```

to:

```
// Something
```

Comment: yes, but I don't want to duplicate the code, i.e. it should be working both on button press, as well as activated from within the script.

Comment: Pressing the button will cause the script to be reloaded, so you don't need to duplicate the code; just change it as above.

Comment: What does "activated" by a script mean? If you need to call code twice, just push it into a function and call the function twice.